# use of linked list to write/read in file

Tags: c, eclipse, data-structures, linked-list

```
struct DETAIL
{
     char data[12+1];
     struct DETAIL* next;
};
int main()
{
    int ret = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("linked","w+");
    struct DETAIL *ptr = NULL;
    struct DETAIL *stTmp = NULL;
    int i = 0;   
    stTmp = (struct DETAIL*)malloc(sizeof(struct DETAIL));
    ptr = (struct DETAIL*)malloc(sizeof(struct DETAIL));
    for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        sprintf(stTmp->data,"%012d",i+1);
        ptr->next = stTmp;
        ret= fwrite((struct DETAIL *)&(ptr->next),1,sizeof(struct DETAIL),fp));                 
        printf("data[%d]:%s\r\n",i,ptr->next->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

The issue faced is on eclipse luna,I want to write the data using linked 
list in file.I want to write 10 records into the file, while writing into the file the dummy datas are being written. But the datas are being printed correctly. Your help will make me stronger in programming. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr->next` **is** a pointer to struct. In C you should never explicitely cast to/from a `void *` because it will mask compiler warnings. To fix your code, you can just write:

```
ret= fwrite(ptr->next,1,sizeof(struct DETAIL),fp);
```

But it does not really make sense to store pointers into a file... Storing only the data part would be better IMHO:

```
ret= fwrite(ptr->next->data,1,sizeof(stTmp->data),fp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Ballesta, it works fine here.one thing i came to know that typecasting is not necessary for linked list as we are passing pointer.thanks again..